# Using SVN Guava encapsulated in an Eclipse/OSGi plugin

Tags: java, guava

So I have two issues. The first one is how do I compile guava from trunk? There are some features there that would be really useful for me. I know they might be changed, I'm willing to live with that.

The second one is: does this process become easier if I want to encapsulate guava from trunk into an Eclipse/OSGi plugin? Otherwise, I can just compile Guava and insert the JARs into an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Are you using an eclipse plug-in for SVN?

Comment: I'm using a Team Connector which depends on an SVN plug-in, so yes.